# Google Home -> Dialogflow entity matching very bad? for non dictonary enities

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

with Dialogflow (API.AI) I find the problem that names from vessel are not well matched when the input comes from google home.

It seems as the speech to text engine completly ignore them and just does the speech to text based on dictionary so Dialogflow cant match the resulting text all at the end.

Is it really like that or is there some way to improve?

Thanks and 
Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend look at [Dialogflow's training feature](https://dialogflow.com/docs/training) to identify where the speech recognition of the Google Assistant may not have worked they way you expect.  In those cases, you'll see how Google's speech recognition detected words you may not have accounted for.  In cases where you'd like to match these unrecognized words to a entity value, simply [add them as synonyms](https://dialogflow.com/docs/entities#dev-mapping).